# How do I redirect /shop to /shop/subfolder every time, using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

How do I redirect `/shop` to `/shop/subfolder` every time? I've been attempting without success, but it's been creating an endless loop (`example.com/shop/subfolder/shop/subfolder`...).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shop/subfolder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? Do you want to "redirect" or "rewrite" the request? How did you know it's creating an endless loop as you suggest?

Comment: Are you trying to redirect `/shop`, or `/shop/` optionally followed by other characters (e.g. `/shop/foobar`? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72425989/edit) to be more specific.

Comment: @MrWhite I have several (shown below). I think redirect, but I'm not familiar with the difference. I know because I test the link and the URL repeats.

# protect htaccess file
<files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</files>

# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# prevent folder listing
IndexIgnore *

# protect against DOS attacks by limiting file upload size
LimitRequestBody 10240000

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^\/?(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# disable the signature
ServerSignature Off

Comment: @kmoser I'm trying to redirect /shop, but may as well redirect /shop and /shop/. I do not want to redirect anything else. Especially because I want to redirect to a folder inside shop.

Comment: If you are only attempting to redirect `/shop` and `/shop/`, why does your RewriteRule include `$1` since there will be nothing after `/shop` or `/shop/`? In any case, your RewriteCond pattern should probably be `^/shop/?$`, which means `/shop` optionally followed by a trailing slash.

Comment: You need to edit your question to include your complete `.htaccess` file, with these directives in-place. The unformatted code in your comment is impossible to read - it looks like elements are missing (perhaps due to the formatting). Is `/shop` or `/shop/subfolder` a physical filesystem directory? "I know because I test the link and the URL repeats." - Except that the rule in your question would not do that by itself (it's not an external redirect).